# asp:LoginName displays Email instead of username

Tags: asp.net, membership

I'm having a peculiar problem. First of all the asp:LoginName displays the Email instead of the signed username.
This is the way I used to create a new user:

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(sAlias, sPassword, sEmail);
```

Also when I check the value of

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

and also

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

they both contain the Email instead of the username.

Login I can perform regularly, no problem.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you using a custom membership provider?

Comment: No, I'm using ASP.NET's default provider, but I didn't use ASP.NET's controls for registration and login.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you check the value of:

```
Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

Just an idea, that might be useful. If that doesn't help, I'll try to see what I can do tomorrow, because I have to go to bed now. :)

Comment: Hi, I tried it and I got: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Even though I was signed in.